# Make Chained Products work for programmatically added orders

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce Chained Products. At the same time, I am using another plugin that imports orders from external sales system similar to eBay. What I want is to make chained products to appear also for imported orders.

What I intended to do:
1. hook right after an order is created
2. Get order items
3. For each item check if there are any chained products set
4. If yes, add these products to the order.

The code I came up with (built using knowledge from a few other posts from Stackoverflow):

```
    function validate_order($order_id)
{
    $order = new \WC_Order($order_id);
    $user_meta = get_user_meta($order->get_user_id());
    if($user_meta)
        return true;
    return false;
}



add_action('wp_insert_post', function($order_id)
{
    if(!did_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed') 
        && get_post_type($order_id) == 'shop_order'
        && validate_order($order_id))
    {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();    
            $chained_products = unserialize(get_post_meta( $product_id, '_chained_product_detail', true ));
            if ($chained_products){
                foreach ($chained_products as $chained_product_id => $chianed_product){

                    $new_product_price = 0; 
                    $quantity = 1;

                    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
                    $product = wc_get_product( $chained_product_id );

                    // Change the product price
                    $product->set_price( $new_product_price );


                    // Add the product to the order
                    $order->add_product( $product, $quantity);
                }
            }
        }

        $order->calculate_totals(); // updating totals

        $order->save(); // Save the order data
    }
});
```

For some reason, it does not work :(

Things to consider:

1.Chained products are saved in variation post meta so maybe line:

```
$product_id = $item->get_product_id();
```

should be

```
$product_id = $item->get_variation_id();
```

However, in both cases, it does not work.

2. I need this code not to add chained products if they are already added.

Thanks in advance.
HoGo

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the $chained_products keep throwing error like unserialize() expect a string instead got an array, here is the reason why;

unserialize() takes string only and what you will end up when you run get_post_meta( $product_id, '_chained_product_detail', true ); is an array of chained products. So that is the reason why you can't get that code to work.